# Android emulator inside Docker container has no internet

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator

I am running an Android emulator inside a Docker container in AWS EC2 size g4dn.2xlarge. Docker base image is Ubuntu.

If I run it with SDK image version "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" with API level 25 I have internet access and a screen shows Wi-fi icon:

[API level 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyXPo.png)

But if I use "system-images;android-23;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" with API level 23  emulators doesn't have internet and it doesn't show Wi-fi icon:

[API level 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASmL5.png)

And I don't have internet on that device.

This is how I am running the emulator command :

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -ports 5554,5555 -avd MyAVD -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -memory 512 -no-window -no-audio -gpu auto -no-boot-anim -nocache -wipe-data
```

I am lowering the API level in an attempt of improving performance because I am getting slower with SDK Image with API level 25.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I had :

hw.gsmModem=no

In my $ANDROID_HOME/avd/config.ini file.

Removing that and re-starting emulator fixed the issue.